# How to filter the data using below given code

Tags: sql, plsql, plsql-package

Below given code will give all data from all the tables present in HR user and i want to use the same code to filter the data from all the tables by using ID columns.Can i do that with same code?

```
    EXEC to_check_data('employees');
    EXEC to_check_data('departments');
    EXEC to_check_data('countries');
    EXEC to_check_data('locations');
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE to_check_data (
    p_table IN VARCHAR2) 
    IS
    TYPE t_list IS TABLE OF user_tab_columns%rowtype INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    v_array         t_list;
    to_store_column VARCHAR2(32767);
    v_number        NUMBER;
    v_varchar       VARCHAR2(32767);
    v_date          DATE;
    v_cursor        PLS_INTEGER;
    v_count         PLS_INTEGER;
    v_column_name   VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
    SELECT
        *
    BULK COLLECT
    INTO v_array
    FROM
        user_tab_columns
    WHERE
        table_name = upper(p_table);

    to_store_column := v_array(1).column_name;
    FOR i IN 2..v_array.count LOOP
        to_store_column := to_store_column
                           || ','
                           || v_array(i).column_name;
    END LOOP;

    v_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    dbms_sql.parse(v_cursor, 'select '
                             || to_store_column
                             || ' from '
                             || p_table, dbms_sql.native);

    FOR idx IN 1..v_array.count LOOP
        IF v_array(idx).data_type = 'NUMBER' THEN
            dbms_sql.define_column(v_cursor, idx, 1);
        ELSIF v_array(idx).data_type IN ( 'VARCHAR2', 'VARCHAR', 'CHAR' ) THEN
            dbms_sql.define_column(v_cursor, idx, 'Dumy Text', v_array(idx).char_length);
        ELSIF v_array(idx).data_type = 'DATE' THEN
            dbms_sql.define_column(v_cursor, idx, sysdate);
        END IF;

        v_column_name := v_column_name
                         || '  '
                         || rpad(v_array(idx).column_name, 20);

    END LOOP;

    dbms_output.put_line(v_column_name);
    v_number := dbms_sql.execute(v_cursor);
    WHILE dbms_sql.fetch_rows(v_cursor) > 0 LOOP
        v_column_name := NULL;
        FOR t IN 1..v_array.count LOOP
            IF v_array(t).data_type = 'NUMBER' THEN
                dbms_sql.column_value(v_cursor, t, v_number);
                v_column_name := v_column_name
                                 || '  '
                                 || rpad(nvl(to_char(v_number), ' '), 20);

            ELSIF v_array(t).data_type IN ( 'VARCHAR2', 'VARCHAR', 'CHAR' ) THEN
                dbms_sql.column_value(v_cursor, t, v_varchar);
                v_column_name := v_column_name
                                 || '  '
                                 || rpad(nvl(to_char(v_varchar), ' '), 20);

            ELSIF v_array(t).data_type = 'DATE' THEN
                dbms_sql.column_value(v_cursor, t, v_date);
                v_column_name := v_column_name
                                 || '  '
                                 || rpad(nvl(to_char(v_date), ' '), 20);

            END IF;
        END LOOP;

        dbms_output.put_line(v_column_name);
    END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: please indent your code properly.

Comment: Please check now